# Name has invalid chars in Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, save, system.io.file

I am currently working on a Save/Load System for my game in unity. But I have no idea what I did wrong. Here is my error:

Here is my error:

> ArgumentException: Name has invalid chars
> System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare,int)
> System.IO.File.Create (System.String path, System.Int32 bufferSize) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> System.IO.File.Create (System.String path) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> InventoryObject.Save () (at Assets/Items/Inventory/Scipts/InventoryObject.cs:30)
> Player.Update () (at Assets/Player/Inventory/Player.cs:22)

And here is the rest of my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Inventory", menuName = "Inventory System/Inventory")]
public class InventoryObject : ScriptableObject, ISerializationCallbackReceiver
{
    public string savePath;
    public ItemDatabaseObject database;
    public List<InventorySlot> Container = new List<InventorySlot>();
    public void AddItem(ItemObject _item, int _amount)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Container.Count; i++)
        {
            if(Container[i].item == _item)
            {
                Container[i].AddAmount(_amount);
                return;
            }
        }
        Container.Add(new InventorySlot(database.GetId[_item],_item, _amount));
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        string savePath = JsonUtility.ToJson(this, true);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create(string.Concat(Application.persistentDataPath, savePath));
        bf.Serialize(file, savePath);
        file.Close();
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        if(File.Exists(string.Concat(Application.persistentDataPath, savePath)))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(string.Concat(Application.persistentDataPath, savePath), FileMode.Open);
            JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(bf.Deserialize(file).ToString(), this);
            file.Close();
        }
    }

    public void OnAfterDeserialize()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Container.Count; i++)
        Container[i].item = database.GetItem[Container[i].ID];
    }

    public void OnBeforeSerialize()
    {
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class InventorySlot
{
    public int ID;
    public ItemObject item;
    public int amount;
    public InventorySlot(int _id, ItemObject _item, int _amount)
    {
        ID = _id;
        item = _item;
        amount = _amount;
    }
    public void AddAmount(int value)
    {
        amount += value;
    }
}
```

If you have any questions, ask them, cuz I really want to fix this stupid bug!

Comment: Usually you'd want to use `Path.Combine` to build the path, not `string.Concat`. Since `savePath` is a blob of json it's likely not going to work as the filename.

Comment: If you supplied an example filename you might see what’s wrong. But as Retired Ninja says if it’s a chunk of json it’s highly likely it’s not valid

Comment: Change the variable name `savePath` to something else, like `saveData` here: `string savePath = JsonUtility.ToJson(this, true);` and here: `bf.Serialize(file, savePath);`

Answer (score 0):

The name of the files cannot have some characters which are exceptions. In windows OS, you cannot have any file name which has the characters as shown in the image below.

[image]

Print the name of the file to the console and check if there are any invalid characters.

```
Debug.Log("file name: " + string.Concat(Application.persistentDataPath, savePath));
```

Comment: It says `    "savePath": "inventory.Save",`, so no, there are no invalid characters?